# How To Properly Assign A Variable In A Loop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm writing a rake task for my Ruby on Rails application. I'm currently just making sure it is accessing the correct fields, and have written this so far:

```
namespace :abc do 
  desc "Used to generate a new daily log"

  task :create_post => :environment do
    User.find_each do |currentUser|
      STARTING_DATE = currentUser.start_date
      puts STARTING_DATE
    end

   puts "It worked yo"      

  end
end
```

When I run this rake task the output to the command line is:

```
$ rake abc:create_post
2017-05-02 03:34:20 UTC
C:/Users/vanbeeandr/workspace/online_journal/lib/tasks/create_post.rake:7: warning: already initialized constant STARTING_DATE
C:/Users/vanbeeandr/workspace/online_journal/lib/tasks/create_post.rake:7: warning: previous definition of STARTING_DATE was here
2017-04-02 03:34:28 UTC
It worked yo
```

Whereas I'd expect the output to simply be:

```
$ rake abc:create_post
2017-05-02 03:34:20 UTC
2017-04-02 03:34:28 UTC
It worked yo
```

Am I assigning the `STARTING_DATE` variable wrong? I'm not really used to Ruby so I'm not sure why this is causing the error.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case matters in Ruby, and `UPPERCASE_NAMES` denote constants. You should not reassign them, which you're doing when you repeatedly assign a value (even the same value) to the constant inside a loop.

Either:

- Move the constant outside the loop if it's a real constant (it doesn't appear to be in your case)
- Don't use a constant for non-constant values (ie use `starting_date = currentUser.start_date`)

Comment: Perfect, thanks for taking the time to solve my problem & explain the error too :)